# Excel VBA making a drop down list appear only once for each distinct value in an ordered column containing duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have one ordered column, ColumnA, containing a list of IDs with some duplicates. I have another column, ColumnB, with a non dependent drop down list next to each ID (including the duplicates) in ColumnA. The drop down list is the same for each value in Column A. 
 I would like to make it so the drop down list only appears once for each distinct ID, and the drop down list box fills the cells in ColumnB with the same corresponding ID.

Any pointers or directions would be really appreciated.

At the moment I have the following code for the drop down list (Admittedly taken and edited from another Stack Overflow Q&A):

```
LastRow = 6 + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(p_CurrentWorkbook).Cells(Rows.count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).row - ActiveCell.row
Dim Mylist(1) As String
Mylist(0) = "Male"
Mylist(1) = "Female"
With Range("B7:B" & LastRow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(Mylist, ",")
End With
```

Comment: if i understood your question you have to control with for loop the columnA.for example if you have 100 rows, and you are to add list at row 5 you have to control the id if is present into 4 rows before .if there is not the id you add your list( your code)at row 5, else no and so on... sorry for my english...